# Compiling ModSecurity in NGINX OSS

Tags: nginx, mod-security

I am trying to compile ModSecurity for the Nginx OSS web server.  I have followed all of the instructions from their "Quick Start Guide", but am running into an issue. After linking up the new module, the config test fails.

Error output from `/var/log/nginx/error.log` is:

`2018/02/10 00:47:51 [emerg] 6026#6026: module "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-modsecurity.conf:1`

originally the dynamic module was compiled with

`sh
./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=../ModSecurity-nginx`

but this results in the error.

from what I've read, I need to compile the module with identical options as the existing Nginx instance.

I found the current options using `nginx -V`, and then re-ran the `./configure` using all of the output options, but this gives the same error.

Can anyone point me down the right path here?

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE 10/29/18

It seems the original binary also needs to be compiled with the `--with-compat` flag. I have submitted a bug report on the issue that can be found here:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=897926

Maybe it can get some traction.

Comment: Hi Andrew Brown, could you solve the issue? If so then how? Me too is facing the same issue. My Nginx version is 1.10.3. Thanks

Comment: I have not seen any movement on the bug report, but apparently the newest Nginx in the Ubuntu repository is compiled with `--with-compat`!  hooray!  I'm still messing around with getting it setup completely, but I've made it farther that ever before.  You'll probably have to upgrade from 1.10.3.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I was using Nginx 1.10.3 which is the default for Debian Stretch. This version does not seem to work with the latest Nginx ModSecurity connector.

I removed the default Nginx version and installed the latest stable Nginx from http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html. After that I was able to install and load the ModSecurity module for Nginx without problems. I followed this guide: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/modsecurity-and-nginx for installing the ModSecurity module for Nginx.

The latest stable version of Nginx which is 1.14.2 supports the **--with-compat** flag. When compiling Nginx source code make sure to use the same compiler options that were used with your running Nginx. To find out which compile time options were used to build your currently running Nginx, run the command: **nginx -V**